# update with mysql subquery error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, subquery

i am trying to update the field 'cancellation_date' of the order table with the most current field of the historical_state_order table, but it gives me an error " Subquery returns more than 1 row" and I can not do it, could someone enlighten me? Thank you.

The update query:

```
    UPDATE orden o 
SET 
    fecha_cancelacion = (SELECT             
                MAX(CAST(fecha AS DATETIME))
        FROM
            historico_estados_orden h
        WHERE
            o.id_orden = h.id_orden
                AND h.estado_origen = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
                AND h.estado_fin = ''
                OR h.estado_fin = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
                AND h.deleted = 0
                AND id_orden NOT IN (3258 , 3221, 3219, 2857, 2836, 2861, 2884, 2878, 3442, 2876)
        GROUP BY h.id_orden)
WHERE
    o.status = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
        AND o.deleted = 0
        AND o.id_orden NOT IN (3258 , 3221, 3219, 2857, 2836, 2861, 2884, 2878, 3442, 2876);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `GROUP BY` in the subquery because you only want a single max value to be returned:

```
UPDATE orden o 
SET fecha_cancelacion =
(
    SELECT MAX(CAST(fecha AS DATETIME))
    FROM historico_estados_orden h
    WHERE
        o.id_orden = h.id_orden AND
        h.estado_origen = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada' AND
        h.estado_fin IN ('', 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada') AND
        h.deleted = 0
)
WHERE
    o.status = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada' AND
    o.deleted = 0 AND
    o.id_orden NOT IN (3258, 3221, 3219, 2857, 2836, 2861, 2884, 2878, 3442, 2876);
```

Also note that the restriction on `id_orden` doesn't need to appear again in the subquery because it already exists in the outer query.  There is a condition that `id_orden` matches between the outer query and subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Do **LIMIT 1**

```
UPDATE orden o 
SET 
    fecha_cancelacion = (SELECT             
                MAX(CAST(fecha AS DATETIME))
        FROM
            historico_estados_orden h
        WHERE
            o.id_orden = h.id_orden
                AND h.estado_origen = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
                AND h.estado_fin = ''
                OR h.estado_fin = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
                AND h.deleted = 0
                AND id_orden NOT IN (3258 , 3221, 3219, 2857, 2836, 2861, 2884, 2878, 3442, 2876)
        GROUP BY h.id_orden LIMIT 1)
WHERE
    o.status = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada'
        AND o.deleted = 0
        AND o.id_orden NOT IN (3258 , 3221, 3219, 2857, 2836, 2861, 2884, 2878, 3442, 2876);
```

If you need **ORDER BY fecha** do so also